# Hydrostatic stress and principal stress relation and Eigenvalue calculation

Tags: condensed-matter, material-science, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

Why does the Eigenvalue in a Stress matrix calculate out to be

$$\sigma = \dfrac{1}{3}\text{tr}(\hat{\sigma}).$$

I pretty much understand why Eigenvalues of a Stress matrix equals principal stress, however how do I relate principal stress with hydrostatic stress? 
Factually they seem to be totally different.

Please give me an intuition on the relation between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise of your question is wrong: The trace of the stress tensor is not (in general) one of the eigenvalues.

The stress tensor $\sigma$ is symmetric, so it can be diagonalised with real eigenvalues, which are called principal stresses and usually denoted (in three dimensions) $\sigma_1$ to $\sigma_3$.

The name "principal stress" is chosen because if you imagine a little  cube-shaped elemnt of the material which is oriented along the eigenvectors, the stresses of the sides of the cube will be just $\sigma_1$ to $\sigma_3$, without any shear components. In other words, the cube is just squeezed or stretched in the pricipal stress directions, but not distorted.

What you have written ist the hydrostatic (or isotropic or mean) stress, which may be denoted by $\sigma_0$ (or $\sigma_\text{m}$ or $p$ -- conventions vary). It is the average stress acting at that position, and can be expressed as the mean of the principal stresses:
$$\sigma_0=\frac13\text{tr} \,\sigma= \frac13\left(\sigma_1+\sigma_2+\sigma_3\right)$$
(To see this, note that the trace is basis-independent and consider a diagonal $\sigma$.) If you again consider the cube-shaped volume element, $\sigma_0$ tells you how much overall pressure the element feels, i.e. the mean value of the stress from all sides.

One use isotropic stress is that you can decompose the stress tensor in the isotropic and deviatoric parts,
$$\sigma=\sigma^\text{d} +\sigma_0 \mathbb{1}\,,$$
and many processes respect this split (i.e. volumetric vs. shear deformations).

Comment: Thankyou for your reply but please tell me something why are real eigen values equal to principal stress and why would I require them from filtering the hydrostatic values?You mentioned about $\sigma_{0}$ being equal to mean stress but why do you clam that.Is it from definition or calculation?That is what I am asking.

Comment: @user586228 I have tried to clarify these points.